# <p:commandButton/> not doing anything

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Im starting a new project and im not getting any errors... but when i insert my data into the fields and press my button to do login nothing happens... no errors no nothing... and it does not even call the method... just a blank console.

heres my code:

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
            <!-- jQuery 2.2.0 -->
            <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
            <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!-- iCheck -->
            <script src="plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
        <h:head>
          <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></meta>
          <title>EnlaceRH | Log in</title>
          <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
          <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"></meta>
          <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
          <!-- Font Awesome -->
         <link href="resources/font-awesome-4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>
          <!-- Ionicons -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css"></link>
          <!-- Theme style -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css"></link>
          <!-- iCheck -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css"></link>
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/img/favicon.ico" />
          <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
          <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
          <script src="resources/js/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script src="resources/js/load.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </h:head>
        <h:body onload="inicio();">
            <f:loadBundle basename="org.enlacerh.util.MessagesBundle_es_VEN" var="msg" />
        <div class="login-box">
          <div class="login-logo">
          </div>
          <!-- /.login-logo -->
          <div class="login-box-body">
            <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>

           <form id="loginform">
           <fieldset>
              <div class="form-group">
               <p:inputText id="usuario" styleClass="form-control" style="height:50px; margin-bottom: 10px;" maxlength="100"
                required="false" value="#{loginBean.usuario}" requiredMessage="#{bd.getMessage('loginuser')}" />
                <p:message for="usuario" />
                <p:watermark for="usuario" value="#{msg.logUsuario}:*" />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <p:password id="clave" feedback="false" styleClass="form-control"
                style="height:50px; margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 10px;"  maxlength="150" required="false"
                requiredMessage="#{bd.getMessage('loginclave')}" value="#{loginBean.clave}" />
                <p:message for="clave" />
                <p:watermark for="clave" value="#{msg.logClave}:*" />
              </div>
              <div class="row">

                <!-- /.col -->
                    <p:ajaxStatus id="ajaxStatusPanel">
                                            <f:facet name="default">
                                                <p:commandButton value="#{msg.login}"
                                                    styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"
                                                    action="#{loginBean.login}" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <f:facet name="start">
                                                <center><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-4x"></i></center>
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <f:facet name="complete">
                                                <p:commandButton value="#{msg.login}"
                                                    styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"
                                                    action="#{loginBean.login}" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:ajaxStatus>

                <!-- /.col -->
              </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>

          </div>
        </div>

        </h:body>
        </html>
```

and my BEAN:

```
            package org.enlacerh.util;

            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.sql.SQLException;

            import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
            import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
            import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
            import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
            import javax.naming.NamingException;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
            import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

            import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
            import org.quartz.SchedulerException;

            @ManagedBean
            @SessionScoped
            public class LoginBean extends Bd {

                private String usuario;
                private String clave;
                FacesMessage msj = null;
                HttpSession sesionOk;
                HttpServletRequest rq = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
                private String sessionId;
                StringMD md = new StringMD(); //Objeto encriptador
                String logged = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("usuario");
                String loggedUsr = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("desuser");


                public String getUsuario ()
                {
                    return usuario;
                }


                public void setUsuario (final String usuario)
                {
                    this.usuario = usuario.toUpperCase();
                }


                public String getClave ()
                {
                    return clave;
                }


                public void setClave (final String clave)
                {
                    this.clave = clave;
                }


                /**
                 * @return the sessionId
                 */
                public String getSessionId() {
                    return sessionId;
                }


                /**
                 * @param sessionId the sessionId to set
                 */
                public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
                    this.sessionId = sessionId;
                }


                /**
                 * Leer Datos de Usuarios
                 * <p>
                 * Se conecta a la base de datos y valida el usuario y la contraseÃ±a.
                 * Adicionalmente valida si el usuario existe ne la base de datos.
                 * @throws IOException 
                 * @return String
                 * @throws SQLException 
                 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
                 * @throws SchedulerException 
                 * @throws InterruptedException 
                 * **/
                public void login() throws NamingException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, SchedulerException, InterruptedException, IOException {
                    Bvt002 seg = new Bvt002(); // Crea objeto para el login
                    String[][] tabla = null;
                    int rows = 0;
                    // LLama al mÃ©todo que retorna el usuario y la contraseÃ±a
                    seg.selectLogin(usuario, JNDI);
                    tabla = seg.getArray();
                    rows = seg.getRows();
                    //System.out.println("MÃ©todo");

                    if (rows == 0) {
                        msj = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, getMessage("noreg"), "");
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msj);
                     usuario = "";
                    }

                    //Se asignan a dos variables String ya que retorna un arreglo y debe convertirse a String
                    // y se convierte en mayÃºscula
                    if(rows>0){
                    String vLusuario = tabla[0][0].toUpperCase().toString();
                    String vLclave = tabla[0][1].toString();
                    //System.out.println("Usuario: " + vLusuario);
                    //System.out.println("Clave: " + vLclave);

                    //Valida que usuario y claves sean los mismos, realiza el login y crea la variable de session
                    if(usuario.equals(vLusuario) && !md.getStringMessageDigest(clave,StringMD.SHA256).equals(vLclave)){
                        //System.out.println(getMessage("logCl"));
                        msj = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, getMessage("logCl"), "");
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msj);

                    } else  if(usuario.equals(vLusuario) && md.getStringMessageDigest(clave,StringMD.SHA256).equals(vLclave)){
                        //System.out.println("Usuario y contraseÃ±a correctos");

                        //Creando la variable de session    
                        sesionOk = ( HttpSession ) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
                        sesionOk.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
                        //sesionOk.setMaxInactiveInterval(getSession());
                        sessionId = sesionOk.getId();
                        //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("usuario", usuario);
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("login", usuario.toUpperCase());
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("rol", tabla[0][2].toString());
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("desuser", tabla[0][3].toString());
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("session", sessionId);

                        //Se genera opciÃ³n de logout
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("logoutEstandart", "0");
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("instancia", tabla[0][5].toString());
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/enlacerh/ct/openbizview.xhtml"); 

                        new Programacion().recuperarTriggers("0");
                    } 

                    }//Fin if valida que sema mayor a cero (0)
                }


                /**
                 * Define la instancia seleccionada y redirecciona
                 */
                 public void grupos(String grupo){
                     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("instancia", grupo.split(" - ")[0]);
                     //System.out.println("Grupo de usuario: " + grupo.split(" - ")[0]);
                     try {
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/enlacerh/ct/openbizview.xhtml");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                 }


                /**
                 * Invalida la session y sale de la aplicaciÃ³n
                 * @return String
                 */ 
                public void logout() throws IOException{
                    String logoutEstandart = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("logoutEstandart");
                    //Invalida la session
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
                    //Redirecciona la pÃ¡gina
                    //System.out.println("PPPPPPPPPPPPP: " + logoutEstandart);
                    if(logoutEstandart==null) {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/enlacerh/login.xhtml"); 
                    } else if(logoutEstandart.equals("1")){
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(LOGOUT_URL);    
                    } else {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/enlacerh/login.xhtml");   
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Retorna el nombre de la sesiÃ³n activa.
                 * Si la sesiÃ³n es null,
                 * entonces llama al mÃ©todo logout que la invalida
                 * redirecciona al logout, retornando blanco.
                 * @return String
                 */ 
                public String getLogged() throws IOException {      //System.out.println("Usuario Logeado:" + logged);
                    if (!rq.isRequestedSessionIdValid() || logged==null) {
                        //rq.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('yourdialogid').show()");
                        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('idleDialog').show()");
                        return null;
                    } else {
                    return logged.toLowerCase();
                    }       
                }

                /**
                 * Retorna el nombre de la sesiÃ³n activa.
                 * Si la sesiÃ³n es null,
                 * entonces llama al mÃ©todo logout que la invalida
                 * redirecciona al logout, retornando blanco.
                 * @return String
                 */ 
                public String getLoggedUsr() throws IOException {       //System.out.println("Usuario Logeado:" + login);
                    if (!rq.isRequestedSessionIdValid() || logged==null) {
                        //rq.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('yourdialogid').show()");
                        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('idleDialog').show()");
                        return null;
                    } else {
                    return loggedUsr.toUpperCase();
                    }       
                }

                public void isLogged() throws IOException{
                    //Redirecciona la pÃ¡gina
                    //System.out.println("Epa: " + logged);
                    if (logged!=null) {
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/enlacerh/ct/openbizview.xhtml"); 
                        //System.out.println("Ya se logeÃ³, redireccionar");
                    }
                    //FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/ri/faces/jsf/openbizview.xhtml"); 
                }


            }
```

hope you guys can help me with this.

Comment: I Think you want to change `@ManagedBean` to `@Named` I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question.

Comment: This is a jsp question.

Comment: Try using h:form instead of plain HTML form 1st of all

Comment: Thx Nikola, that was it... i have bout 2 years of expirience programing and im amazed how are the small details that keep givin me trouble... instead of a major problem.